# how can i add this url in my script without breaking current loop using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

```
    while True:
         try:
            time.sleep(2)
            browser.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
         except:
            time.sleep(2)
            browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'Restart Battle')]").click()
```

is there way to add this url without breaking the above loop and when this url shows up
it redirects towards main.py file?

```
browser.get(url)
```

Comment: Clarify your question, it does not have any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not. Not that I know of. Usually if there is keyboard or mouse interaction it ends a loop.